# Error when using selfhosted (Jetty) Metabase with ssl inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, ssl, jetty, metabase

I'm trying to setup a self hosted (Jetty) Metabase inside a docker container running with ssl enabled.

First I created the `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` using the [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-other), than converted to `keystore.jks` using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/xkr47/920ffe94f6a4c171ee59).

Then created a .env file that would be used for the `--env-file` docker flag:

```
MB_DB_FILE=/metabase/metabase.db
MB_JETTY_SSL=true
MB_JETTY_SSL_PORT=443
MB_JETTY_SSL_KEYSTORE=./keystore.jks
MB_JETTY_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=my-pass
```

And tried to run:

```
docker run -p 80:3000 -v ~/metabase:/metabase --env-file "./prod.env" --name metabase metabase/metabase
```

But I got the following error:

```
ERROR metabase.core :: Metabase Initialization FAILED
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:345) ~[metabase.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310) ~[metabase.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80) ~[metabase.jar:?]
```

Solved by changing the SSL_PORT to 8443, so the new env file looks like this:

```
MB_DB_FILE=/metabase/metabase.db
MB_JETTY_SSL=true
MB_JETTY_SSL_PORT=8443
MB_JETTY_SSL_KEYSTORE=./keystore.jks
MB_JETTY_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=my-pass
```

Deleted the old container and started a new one with the env file above but now I'm stuck on this error:

```
ERROR metabase.core :: Metabase Initialization FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException: /"./keystore.jks" is not a valid keystore
```

I've double checked if my .jks file is valid using [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/validate-that-certificates-are-correctly-imported-into-the-java-keystore-639238418.html). And it is.

My questions are:

1. Why can't I run it on 443
2. Why is my keystore not valid?

Edit 1:

Following up Joakim's suggestion:

Changed to the absute path

```
MB_DB_FILE=/metabase-prod-data/metabase.db
MB_JETTY_SSL=true
MB_JETTY_SSL_PORT=8443
MB_JETTY_SSL_KEYSTORE=/root/services/metabase/setup/keystore.jks
MB_JETTY_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=my-pass
```

Got this error:

```
ERROR metabase.core :: Metabase Initialization FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException: /root/services/metabase/setup/keystore.jks is not a valid keystore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why port 443 is not used is answered by @Joakim

I also faced this issue for metabase initialisation.
The error I was facing was that the keystore file at host is not accessible inside the docker container.

I used docker-compose yml file. You can search for terminal based ways as well.

I made it accessible by adding folder at host which has the certificate by using volume attribute.

```
metabase:
   ...
    env_file:
      - ./config/metabase.env
    volumes:
      - <LOCAL_PATH>:<CONTAINER_PATH>
```

Inside the environment path:

```
MB_JETTY_SSL_KEYSTORE:<CONTAINER_PATH>/keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 1):

443 is a restricted port on most OS's that require root/superuser/admin rights to be able to bind to it.

Your keystore isn't found, that path is invalid.
The error is just confusing.

The configuration you have at

```
MB_JETTY_SSL_KEYSTORE=./keystore.jks
```

Try making that an absolute path, as the metabase is apparently just tacking what you give it onto the end of some other path `/` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Take a look at the Edit 1 I just added to the question. Tried the absolute path but it didn't worked